# Regex: Match everything between characters or new line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to come up with a regex that would identify instances of **abc=123456|123456** from the following snippet:

```
xyz=abcdef|abcdef||abc=123456|123456||cat=dog|dog||foo=bar|bar||
xyz=abcdef|abcdef||abc=123456|123456
xyz=abcdef|abcdef||abc=123456|123456||
abc=123456|123456||xyz=abcdef|abcdef||
```

The requirement here is that the match string can have a trailing double pipe or it could not have it.

I am currently using this:

```
/abc=(.*?)+((?=\|\|)|(?=\r|\n))/
```

But this seems to break with the OR condition for end of match.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Preview link:
http://regexr.com/3be2t

Comment: I used /abc=\d{6}\|\d{6}/ for a very simple match. You're using lookarounds, any specific reason?

Comment: I guess I would need to understand what you are  exactly trying to match, what you're trying to avoid matching, and a precise context for matching. Given what I read that does the trick, but clearly I'm missing something if you felt the need to use lookaround.....

Comment: You might want to give a second look to the `(.*?)+` part. Combining a `*` with a `+` seems redundant and might match more than you originally expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use end of the line anchor instead of `\r` or `\n` and you have to remove the `+` which exists just after to `(.*?)`. With `+`, it does a greedy match and the capturing group must contain an empty string.

```
\babc=(.*?)(?=\|\||$)
```

or

```
\babc=(.*?)(?=\|\||\r|\n)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uB2zS4/1)